# StackExchange OAuth login page style on Windows 8

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

The StackExchange OAuth login form doesn't look good when triggered from a Windows 8 app.
The page should be styled to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar for instance.

See also this StackExchange thread: [How to style control hosting OAuth login dialog of WinRT WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339178/how-to-style-control-hosting-oauth-login-dialog-of-winrt-webauthenticationbroker/13795871)

**Screenshot**

- missing icon/title in page header (white rectangle, top left of dialog)
- horizontal scrollbar
- I think the page width could be bigger

[image: Layout issues]

Comment: The fact that (last I checked) you can't resize that Win8 control doesn't help.

Comment: True, but the web page can be optimized server-side per MSDN guidance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj856908

Answer (score 1):

This was probably fixed in the most recent build.

Don't have my Surface handy to test, but I'll confirm later tonight.